# How can I log into wireless router from Win8?

Tags: windows, networking, router

I recently purchased a new laptop, running Windows 8. It's connected to my home wifi network, and everything works fine. Or at least, I thought it worked fine... until I needed to connect to the router to change a setting.

The Win8 machine cannot connect to the router (192.168.0.1) using any browser. It cannot ping the router. But the router does show up in traceroute and the arp table. I can access the router from other devices on the network, <s>including other PCs</s>, phones, tablets.

---

Edit: In fact... NONE of my windows PCs can reach the admin of this router now. Win7, Vista, XP - all the same. I'm left with iPhones, iPods, and iPad and an Android tablet that can do admin. Weird.

I've tried some of the suggestions from the comments and answers.

- Changing to 192.168.1.1 didn't help.
- Tried adding 192.168.0.1 to list of Trusted Sites under Internet Options, from within IE. Didn't help.

---

My guess is that there's some other security setting that I just don't know about, blocking all but the lowest level traffic. I've uninstalled the Norton security software that came pre-installed, and that hasn't changed anything.

How can I get this working?

#### ipconfig /all

```
C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : fronthall
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : vlan1.phub.net.cable.rogers.com

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : BC-85-56-14-C8-E9
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : BC-85-56-14-C8-F0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : vlan1.phub.net.cable.rogers.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : BC-85-56-14-C8-EF
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b440:2b5a:8b79:989f%14(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.106(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : July 30, 2013 7:28:30 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : July 31, 2013 7:28:30 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 347899222
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-19-3A-D1-9B-D4-C9-EF-68-6B-70

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.4.4
                                       8.8.8.8
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : B1-LINE.COM
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : D4-C9-EF-68-6B-70
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.vlan1.phub.net.cable.rogers.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : vlan1.phub.net.cable.rogers.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 14:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:c6f:b15:518f:2405(Prefer
red)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c6f:b15:518f:2405%19(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

#### Traceroute

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [74.125.225.128]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    13 ms    25 ms    10 ms  67.231.222.25
  4   144 ms    17 ms    14 ms  so-5-0-3.gw02.bloor.phub.net.cable.rogers.com [6
6.185.81.73]
  5    27 ms    27 ms    28 ms  64.71.240.58
  6    28 ms    28 ms    31 ms  72.14.216.189
  7     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  8    30 ms    30 ms    29 ms  209.85.240.152
  9    27 ms    28 ms    29 ms  ord08s09-in-f0.1e100.net [74.125.225.128]

Trace complete.
```

#### arp -a

```
C:\Windows\system32>arp -a

Interface: 192.168.0.106 --- 0xe
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  192.168.0.1           bc-14-01-59-a4-02     dynamic
  192.168.0.100         60-c5-47-5b-d2-75     dynamic
  192.168.0.104         00-22-58-57-81-c4     dynamic
  192.168.0.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
  224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
  224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
  224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
  224.0.0.253           01-00-5e-00-00-fd     static
  239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
  255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
```

Comment: No device on this network has a wired connection. Everything with a screen can be used to admin, except the one Win8 computer.

Comment: I have seen strange issues using classful routing (x.x.0.1). Would it be possible to change your network to a classless (x.x.1.1)?

Comment: What does the DHCP entry for this machine look like on the router? IOW, is there anything odd about the router's entry for the machine?

Comment: @spuder - Thanks for the idea, tried it, didn't help. Same basic result, except of course DHCP tells everyone the gateway is 192.168.1.1. I have a second AP as well, which I _can_ log into... turned it off, changed the router's IP to the one AP2 was using... and can't reach the admin.

Comment: @Fred - I can't get much DHCP detail, but the little that's shown is the same as other machines. MAC address is correct, lease time matches what the PC understands.

Comment: OK, are you using the same browser on all the PCs? Can you try a different browser than what you currently use? Make sure the new browser is set to the normal defaults (no javascript diabled, no proxy, etc.). Also, can you still ping the router from the other PCs?

Comment: @Fred - Haven't tried every browser on every pc, but can't ping from any of them. Router shows up in all pc's arp table. All settings are defaulted.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding 192.168.0.1 to your list of Trusted Sites under Internet Options, from within IE.

Comment: That didn't help. Sounded like a good idea...